# g++ compiler not working for opencv installed inside ros-fuerte

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed `ros-fuerte-desktop-full` and with it opencv got installed. Opencv code is working inside any ros package that I create. However, some times I like to work outside ROS and have Geany installed. I have given the following set build command to geany for compilation

```
g++ "%f" `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o "%e"
```

When I try to build it says:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. No package 'opencv' found.
```

My PKG_CONFIG_PATH already contains opencv.pc file. Here is the output of some flags:

```
#echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/pkgconfig:   //this path contains opencv.pc

#pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
-I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include  -L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab

#pkg-config --libs opencv
-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140346/g++-compiler-not-working-for-opencv-installed-inside-ros-fuerte/) by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're on the right path.

My best guess is that something inside the build system for Geany is unsetting or overriding your PKG_CONFIG_PATH. It may also be worth invoking Geany from a terminal after you've sourced the ROS setup files, instead of launching it directly from the GUI.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-03-17**:
This is pretty weird. Yes something inside Geany is doing making the shift. Anyway, I can compile even using terminal by command: g++ filename.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o output.

Looks fine for me. Thanks.